# In Angular1.5+, how to import and use the independent component?

Tags: angularjs

Now, I write an Angular1.5+ component in one folder.

The component in an independent folder.

My issue is how to use this component in different HTML. In other words, I want to find a method to import this component in more than two HTML files.

[image]

The `cellComponent.js` is like this:

```
function courseCellComponentFun() {
    var ctrl = this;
}

angular.module(app_name).component('courseCell', {
    templateUrl: '../cellComponent.html',
    controller:courseCellComponentFun,
    bindings:{
        cellData:'='
    }
})
```

The `cellComponent.html` is like this:

```
<div class="course_cell">
    <div class="img_box">
        <div ng-bind="$ctrl.cellData.name"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The index.html like this:

```
   <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array1">
        <course-cell cell-data="item"></course-cell>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
        $scope.array1 = [
            {name:'cell1'},
            {name:'cell2'},
            {name:'cell3'},
        ]
    });
</script>
```

**How to import the component in the `index.hmtl`**? My `index.html` does not work now. I can't see the text.

Comment: Have you tried importing the script of your component in the index.html?
something like: `<script src="js/cellComponent.js"></script>`

Comment: If you want to use in several html files, you can export your component... kinda.. `var componentOpts = { templateUrl: "...",  }; export componentOpts`, and then importing in the file you need it `import {componentOpts} from "path/to/file"` and use it in your module: `angular.module("module").component("nameComponent", componentOpts);`

Comment: Thank you very much. I wait for somebody to write a demo as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you're not using Typescript or Babel or the new ES6 standard for importing and exporting modules, I'm affraid you have to add the reference of your component.js file, as simple as `<script src="cellComponent.js"></script>`in the index.html

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="cellComponent.js"></script>
    <script src="appModule.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="item in array1">
           <course-cell cell-data="item"></course-cell>
       </li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**appModule.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.array1 = [
        {name:'cell1'},
        {name:'cell2'},
        {name:'cell3'},
    ];
})
.component("courseCell", componentOpts); // componentOpts comes from the componentOpts.js script
```

**cellComponent.html**

```
<div class="course_cell">
    <div class="img_box">
       <div ng-bind="$ctrl.cellData.name"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**cellComponent.js**

```
function courseCellComponent() {
    var ctrl = this;
}

var componentOpts = {
    templateUrl: './cellComponent.html',
    controller: courseCellComponent,
    controllerAs: "$ctrl",
    bindings: {
        cellData:'=',
    }
};
```

See this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rdZQzLdx9tmcvnTsEr5P?p=preview)

Comment: If I want to use more than one component in the `index.html`. Then I add to reference two components javascript file. How to  use  `.component`  method to implement two components?

Comment: Just chain them: `.component("componentOne", componentoOneOpts).component("componentTwo", componentoTwoOpts).component("componentThree", componentoThreeOpts);`

Comment: If I use the `cellComponent` in different HTML, the template will change the path . How to set the templateUrl to fit multiple paths?